# Update Luis List Entities using REST API

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Is there any Rest API available to update Luis List Entities?

My requirement is to update a specific Luis List Entity dynamically from DB Master Table.

Thank you in Advance.
Kartik!

Comment: Please refer to this link for Update closed list entity API
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c27
and Refer to this Link for LUIS programmatic APIs
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f